# How to get dataframe column value and replace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
id  name   country
1   AAA    Afghanistan
2   BBB    Australia
```

This is my dataframe↑

How to let country become↓

```
id  name   country       Newcountry
1   AAA    Afghanistan   Afg
2   BBB    Australia     Aus
```

I want get 3 words from country column value and add to Newcountry column, how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
In [7]: df['Newcountry'] = df['country'].str[:3]

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   id name      country Newcountry
0   1  AAA  Afghanistan        Afg
1   2  BBB    Australia        Aus
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply()`.

```
df['Newcountry'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x:x[:3])
```

or You can use attribute access.

```
df['Newcountry'] = df1.country.apply(lambda x:x[:3])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works too. But I'm not sure "lambda x:x[:3] " what it means? Can you give me some description?

Comment: lambda is one line function. when you apply on `df['country']` it itterate on  each element one by one, so `x` has all element iterate `df['country']` fields and `x:x[:3]` assign slice value,  ex: country='Afghanistan' then x[:3]='Afg'.

Comment: I hope you got it, if my answer really helpful don't forget to mark.